# Move mailfolder containing emails

Tags: email, move

CheckForFolder checks if a folder with a certain name exsits as a subfolder of Folder.

CreateSubFolder, creates a subfolder under Folder.

The last if should watch out for a certain message in the mail and the condition is right, the whole subfolder (containing then mails) should be moved under the folder "Archiv", but this is sadly the part that doesn't work :(

Any ideas?

```
If CheckForFolder(Folder, newName) = False Then
        If CheckForFolder("Archiv", newName) = False Then
            Set MyFolder = CreateSubFolder(Folder, newName)
                Else
            Set MyFolder = olNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("Archiv").Folders(newName)
            MyFolder.MoveTo (olNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders(Folder))
        End If
            Else
        Set MyFolder = olNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders(Folder).Folders(newName)
    End If
    myItem(i).Move MyFolder

    If InStr(1, message, Closure) > 0 Then
'        MsgBox ("HURRAY")
        Set MyFolder = olNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders(Folder).Folders(newName)
        MyFolder.MoveTo (olNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("Archiv"))
    End If
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an alternativ solution, leaving the for-loop after moving MyItem(i) to MyFolder.

Then I run through every Subfolder of Folder and look out for the Closure in the first email.

Here some code:

```
For i = myItem.Count To 1 Step -1
    lookIn = myItem(i).Subject
    message = myItem(i).Body
    newName = Mid(lookIn, InStr(1, lookIn, IDMarker), 6)   'Getting folder ID with Marker

    If Left(newName, 1) = IDMarker Then
        newName = Replace(newName, IDMarker, "")            'ID without Marker
    End If
    If CheckForFolder(Folder, newName) = False Then
        If CheckForFolder("Archiv", newName) = False Then
            Set MyFolder = CreateSubFolder(Folder, newName)
        End If
    Else
        Set MyFolder = olNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders(Folder).Folders(newName)
    End If
    myItem(i).Move MyFolder
Next

For Each olFolder In olInbox.Folders
    If InStr(1, olFolder.Items(1).Body, Closure) > 0 Then
        olFolder.MoveTo (olNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("Archiv"))
    End If
Next
```